# Keeping a code fold closed after reopening the file

Tags: r, for-loop, rstudio, fold

Does anyone have an idea how to keep a code fold around a `for` loop closed after saving, closing and reopening the file?

I tried to shorten my code via folding in the e.g. the `for` loops.
That it seems structured and clear after opening.

But every time I open my file again, the `for` loops are unfolded.

Comment: I assume you're talking about using the code-folding feature in RStudio?

Comment: I recommend against relying on code folding or similar editor features to organise your code. Organise your code using modularisation, instead: use files, and functions. Properly organised code does not need code folding to be readable.

Comment: (I’m not saying not to use code folding at all, although personally I have fallen out of love with it; I *am* saying that it’s a warning sign if you rely on it to the extent that you want to have folds closed when opening a file; this indicates that your code is too complex and hard to read.)

Comment: Your best bet might be the menu/hotkeys. Edit > Folding > Collapse All and it has a hotkey depending on your OS.